# item.set_item not working on IE

Tags: error, ie

The below code is working fine in chrome but not working for IE.

```
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteURL);
    var oList =clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('MasterNotification');
    var newItem = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.item = oList.addItem(newItem);
    item.set_item("NotificationNumber",WONumber);
```

It's giving below error:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'set_item'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created item by using "this" object, so while accessing also you need to use "this". change this

```
item.set_item("NotificationNumber",WONumber);
```

to

```
this.item.set_item("NotificationNumber",WONumber);
```

or just delete "this". and use var

```
var item = oList.addItem(newItem);
item.set_item("NotificationNumber",WONumber);
```

if you want to use the same 'item' variable in other functions call the other function with this parameter in your success callback. you cannot execute the other function without calling this function. So change your code to use callbacks or you can use jQuery differed Objects to manage the async calls(but it will be confusing for the beginners). change the executeQueryAsync as follows.

```
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
    //call the other function with parameter
     myOtherFunction(item);
    }), function(s,a){alert(a.get_message())});


    function myOtherFunction(item){

    }
```

the cleaner way is using deferred object or call your function with callbacks like

```
   function createItem(successcallback,failcallback){
    //...code to create item
     clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
       successcallback(item);
     },function(s,a){
       failcallback(a.get_message())});
   }

   function functionUsingItem(item){
    //
   }

   function functionToShowError(errMsg){
    //
   }
```

call the createItem method like

```
createItem(functionUsingItem,functionToShowError);
```

Comment: The this.item.set_item("NotificationNumber",WONumber) is not working but 2nd suggestion is working but i want to use the item globally.So now i created a global variable and set the item value to it.but it is not correct way.can u have a other way.

Comment: Do you want to use the variaable in a seperate JS function? how are you calling the executeQueryAsync, are you using callback functions?

Comment: Ya Exactly.I want to use the variable in a separate js functions and other functions.

Comment: clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onsaveEditLaborItem), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));